# In ExtJS, How to suddenly unbind when event fire?

Tags: extjs, event-handling

Goal is to show alert box only first time click.

```
Ext.getCmp('myBtn').on('click', function(){
    alert('Alert this message only in first click.');
    Ext.getCmp('myBtn').un('click', this); // my attempt, still not work
})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would it work if you named your anonymous function? Also, you can get reference to the button from the method call, so you do not need to use `Ext.getCmp()`.

```
Ext.getCmp('myBtn').on('click', function handleClick(button, event){
    alert('Alert this message only in first click.');
    button.removeListener('click', handleClick);
})
```

Comment: I use your solution, with short term of removeListener -> button.un('click', handleClick);

Answer (score 26):

If you want an event to be triggered exactly once, use this:-

```
Ext.getCmp('myBtn').on('click', function(){
    alert('Alert this message only in first click.');
}, null, {single: true});
```

The `{single:true}` will make this anonymous function to be run exactly once after dispatched, so this should accomplish your requirement.

*Note: The `null` is actually the useful scope changer. You might need this to change the scope in the anonymous function*

Check out ExtJS Events @ http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/core_concepts/events.html

Also check the Event Options @ http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-on

Happy ExtJS :)

Answer (score 5):

Try working with a named function rather than anonymous function.

```
var myfunction = function() {

   alert('Alert this message only in first click.');
   Ext.getCmp('myBtn').un('click', myfunction);
}

Ext.getCmp('myBtn').on('click',myfunction);
```

Comment: Work too. Thanks for fast response.